# Why use `devtools::install_github` instead of `remotes::install_github`?

Tags: r, devtools

The [recommendations in](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html) "R Packages (2e)" by Hadley Wickham and Jennifer Bryan leave you with the following installation recommendation in your README file:

```r
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("jennybc/regexcite")
```

However, I frequently use `remotes::install_github` instead since the `remotes` library is much easier to install. I've often been unable install `devtools` at all and when it does install it takes a significant amount of time to do so. In contrast, I've never had a failure installing `remotes` and it installs very quickly. This matters more for running R code on clusters, servers, and Docker images and not standard R Studio setups. I know that the functionality is identical since it originates from `remotes` either way and in other situations "R Packages" encourages using the minimal dependencies possible. Therefore I want to suggest `remotes` instead in my README.

Is there any reason not to recommend `remotes` over `devtools`? The only thing I can think of is that users are more likely to recognize the `devtools` name and know if they have it installed already.

Comment: The recommendation is outdated. Using `remotes::install_github()` is preferable (since that package got split off) as it has a smaller installation footprint.  You adopted the right pattern.

Comment: Also `devtools::install_github` calls the `install_remotes` from the `remotes` package with some overheads. use `remotes` in this case

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: @tgbrooks Thanks, and done (in a slightly expanded answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that recommendation is still in print, it would seems outdated. These days, using `remotes::install_github()` is preferable, and has been since that package got split off.

One reason is that it has a much smaller installation footprint:

```
> db <- tools::CRAN_package_db()
> deps <- tools::package_dependencies(c("devtools", "remotes"), recursive=TRUE, db=db)
> sapply(deps, length)
devtools  remotes 
     101        4 
>
```

(This count is still biased upwards, the four for `remote` are all base R packages.)

So in sum, you adopted the right pattern and can stick with it.